# page create phonegap jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to execute script when the page is loaded but it didn't works

To begin I load my first page with

```
$('#loadingPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {...}
```

this works
I redirect my page to menu.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div date-role="page" id="menuPage"></page>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my script file I have

```
$('#menuPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {alert('bbb')};
$('#menuPage').live('click', function(event) {alert('aaa')};
```

I never have the alert bbb but when I click on my screen I have the alert aaa

The full script code:

http://pastebin.com/Jh676yFZ

Thanks

Comment: If you want send me your example (you will find my mail in my profile) and I will fix it for you. Also don't use pagecreate, use pageshow or pagebeforeshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two problems in your code. Pagecreate should not be used as a page load trigger, it is better to use pagebeforechange and pageshow. This was first problem. Second one was an error in menu.html page formatting, it is also fixed now.

One more thing, this is not an error but I have changed live( with on( function for an event binding. Currently it is not a problem, but live is currently deprecated and I think it wont work any more from jQuery 1.9